# The state doesn't update as it should

Tags: reactjs, setstate

A simple inputfield to update the state.

If you input 5 and click 'Pledge', the 'before' log show 0, but the 'after' log also show 0. If you click the button again then it shows 5, and it continues like that. Like it's always on step behind.

Why is that?

App.js

```
state = {
    fundGoal: 1000,
    amountFunded: 0
  }

  getAmount = amount => {
    console.log('before', this.state.amountFunded)
    const parsedAmount = parseInt(amount)
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      amountFunded: prevState.amountFunded + parsedAmount
    }))
    console.log('after', this.state.amountFunded)
  }
```

Form in another component

```
getAmount = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const value = e.target.elements.amount.value
    this.props.getAmount(value)

    e.target.elements.amount.value = ''
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setState() function runs asynchronously so if you want to see the updated state after setState() has finished running you can pass a callback function to setState as follows

```
getAmount = amount => {
    console.log('before', this.state.amountFunded)
    const parsedAmount = parseInt(amount)
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      amountFunded: prevState.amountFunded + parsedAmount
    }), () => console.log('after', this.state.amountFunded));
  }
```

Comment: Oh, so it's not one step behind only that I didn't log it correctly... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because `setState` is an asynchronous call. There is a callback after the transaction is done.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
      amountFunded: prevState.amountFunded + parsedAmount
    }), () => console.log('after', this.state.amountFunded))
```